# error: return value type does not match the function type

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc

Here is a code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

float conv2D(int rowsKernel, int colsKernel, int rowsImage, int colsImage, float kernel[][5], int image[][15], float imageConvolved[][11]); //Function Prototype definition

float conv2D(int rowsKernel, int colsKernel, int rowsImage, int colsImage, float kernel[][5], int image[][15], float imageConvolved[][11])
{
    int kernelSize;     //This variable represents the size of the Gaussian kernel
    int i;          //variable which controls the rows of an image
    int j;          //variable which controls the columns of an image
    int ii;         //variable which controls the rows of the kernel
    int jj;         //variable which controls the columns of the kernel
    float sum;          //variable that holds the result of convolution for a particular pixel of an image
//float imageConvolved;//Result of an image convolved by a Gaussian kernel
    int imagePixel;
    float kernelPixel;
    kernelSize = colsKernel;    /*Since we consider a square kernel, then rowsKernel=colsKernel, which implies that the size of the                 kernel (kernelSize) equals either of these two variables (that is, kernelSize=colsKernel=rowsKernel) */
    for (i = kernelSize / 2; i < rowsImage - kernelSize / 2; i++)   // perform iteration through the rows of an image
    {
    for (j = kernelSize / 2; j < colsImage - kernelSize / 2; j++)   // perform iteration through the columns of an image
    {
        sum = 0;        /*Initializing the accumulator. This variable will finally contain the convolution result for a particular pixel */
        for (ii = -kernelSize / 2; ii <= kernelSize / 2; ii++)  // perform iteration through the rows of a kernel
        {
        for (jj = -kernelSize / 2; jj <= kernelSize / 2; jj++)  //perform iteration through the columns of a kernel
        {
            imagePixel = image[i + ii][j + jj];
            kernelPixel = kernel[ii + kernelSize / 2][jj + kernelSize / 2];

            sum += imagePixel * kernelPixel;
        }
        }
        imageConvolved[i - kernelSize / 2][j - kernelSize / 2] = sum;
    }
    }
    return (imageConvolved);    // convolved image
}

int main()
{
    float gauss[][5] = {
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
    };
    int img[][15] = {
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
    };
    int rowsK = 5, colsK = 5, rowsI = 15, colsI = 15;
    float result[11][11];
    float Iconv[11][11];
    Iconv = conv2D(rowsK, colsK, rowsI, colsI, gauss, img, result);
    return 0;
}
```

I modified the code as an attempt to try to solve the problem. However, I am getting two errors (using the CCStudio V3.3):

> "convolution.c", line 39: error: return value type does not match the
>   function type "convolution.c", line 71: error: expression must be a
>   modifiable lvalue

Comment: Please paste the **real code**, including the declaration of each and every parameter and their types., **as code**; not buried in a paragraph. Your description, "where the parameters in this function are declared as float result, int rowsK, int colsK, int rowsI and int colsI" is conveniently missing the last two parameter types, and in case it wasn't obvious, they're crucial to finding your problem. It is therefore ironic they aren't included. In short, don't just tell us "about" your code; **show it**.

Comment: What is `imageConvolved`?  You access it as a 2D array and return it as a `float`.  Which do you want?  Also, I agree with the above comment.  Your question is very hard on the eyes.  Include code as code blocks, not as boldface chunks inside a paragraph.

Comment: You say that imageConvolved is defined as float, but you behave it as it is a 2D array. And you returned it from the function which returns float, so it seems it is a bare float value which you try to use as a 2D array.. It might be better if you just copy and paste your code..

Comment: Are you saying that `imageConvolved` is declared like this: `float imageConvolved`? In that case it's clear why the compiler doesn't like it because you are accessing it like a 2d array.

Comment: @ChrisWue it seems imageConvolved is an input parameter and is two dimensional float array.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: Now it is yes, in his original question it wasn't (as you can see a bunch of other people have made similar comments)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning what seems to be a two dimensional array(`imageConvolved`) from a function that returns `float` according to its declaration. I don't know what you mean to return from the function but it seems the error is on this line:

```
return(imageConvolved);
```

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of function `conv2D` is float. However, in the definition you returned `imageConvolved`. `imageConvolved` is an array in your `ormal parameter`, you needn't return it, so you'd return something of `float` type insead.

Comment: The problem has been solved (when I compile using the GCC compiler) . The have made the function conv2D not to return anythinin g at a calling point, and in the main() function I am passing another parameter, which collects the results, to the function conv2D. I can then easily read the result from the main() function.